# Using 'this' selector in new object parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a javascript pong emulator and I want to make it as object oriented as possible. You can see the code here:

[Github repo](https://github.com/ross8/pong/tree/paddle-sizing-fix)

[Codepen showing how the paddle is not rendering](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbXpYw)

You can see the variables that I commented out that were used for paddle sizing. I moved the sizing onto the Paddle and Player object constructors to make it more object oriented.

I have a Paddle object constructor:

```
function Paddle(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width/8;
    this.height = this.width/5;
    this.center = width/2 - this.width/2;
    this.x_speed = 0;
    this.y_speed = 0;
};
```

And a Player object constructor:

```
function Player() {
    this.startX = Paddle.center;
    this.startY = height - Paddle.height;
    this.paddle = new Paddle(this.startX, this.startY);
    this.score = 0;
};
```

I also have similar constructor for the computer player.

At the end of the script I create my objects and start the game:

```
var player = new Player();
var computer = new Computer();
var ball = new Ball(ballStartPositionX,ballStartPositionY);
```

My paddles are not getting created and I think it is due to how I'm using `this.startX = Paddle.center;` and `this.paddle = new Paddle(this.startX, this.startY);`, particularly how I'm using the 'this' selector within the new Paddle parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: You are adding a *centre* property to *Paddle* instances, *Paddle.center* attempts to read a *center* property of the *Paddle* constructor instead (so not really anything to do with *this*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have:

```
function Player() {
    this.startX = Paddle.center;
    this.startY = height - Paddle.height;
    this.paddle = new Paddle(this.startX, this.startY);
    this.score = 0;
};
```

you are attempting to read the *center* property of the *Paddle* constructor, but that is a property of *Paddle* instances. You need to pass the initial *x* and *y* coordinates to the *Player* constructor, so:

```
function Player(x, y) {

    // create paddle instance first
    this.paddle = new Paddle(x, y);

    // Use the paddle instance, not the constructor
    this.startX = this.paddle.center;
    this.startY = height - this.paddle.height; // height is a global
    this.score = 0;
};
```

And when you create a *Player* instance, you have to say where they are:

```
var player = new Player(xCoord, yCoord);
```

so it can use the coords when constructing the *Paddle* instance.